# LM358 / LM324 based op amp distortion fix with diodes?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I found an op-amp designed by New Japanese Radio Co., Ltd called the NJM12904, which is a dual op-amp. It seems to be a distortion-free variant of the quad LM324 / LM2902 or dual LM358 / LM2904 op-amp.

So the question is: Could I get an LM324, LM358 or any of its variants and fix the distortion using diodes in the same configuration as the NJM12904?

Or I could simply buy a few NJM12904 op-amps since they seem to have slightly better specs than the LM324 / LM358. The NJM12904 has a slightly higher slew rate and GBW.

datasheet of the NJM12904 : https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/294/NJM12904_E-221976.pdf

Picture of circuit diagram with the internal diodes :

[image: NJM1904 diagram with diodes]

Comment: Why do you believe that the diodes will decrease distortion?

Comment: @Mattman944 It says in the datasheet of the njm12904 it can be used for audio?

Comment: @MichaelWeaser The chip can be used with audio. Many other chips can too. But whether or not it can be used with audio has nothing to do with the diodes you refer to.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here. There are literally thousands of opamps and you pick the one with the worst distortion and hope to improve it with some external hack? What prevents you from buying an opamp designed for your purpose?

Comment: Are you certain it's not an LM2904 clone.   part numbers often rhyme.

Comment: @Jasen Well its a improved version of their LM2904 clone the NJM2904.  The NJM12904 has slightly better specs than a actual LM324/LM2902, LM358/LM2904 if you read the datasheet.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't fix a LM324 or LM358 distortions by adding diodes as in NJM12904.

The diodes are not there for reducing noise, they are there to protect the inputs and outputs from under- and overvoltage so it does not get damaged so easily.

Comment: doesn't the LM358 have them, too, anyway?

Comment: then it has to be another improvement with the updated design that makes it has lower distortion. There is a older clone called the NJM2904 that has the same specs as an original LM2904. They did seem to have updated to improve their clone with their 12904 , due to the improved slew rate and gbw, and from another document I found it is suppose to have lowered distortion, which is why it probably mentions audio use in the datasheet, while their 2904 clone datasheet says nothing about audio at all.

Answer (score 1):

The NJR part is not better because of diodes. The only "op-amps" I recall acting better in audio use with added diodes are some transconductance amplifiers. They use linearizing diodes at the *input*. The ones still made, like the LM13700, include those diodes, but some earlier types didn't. That's not a typical voltage-controlled op-amp, though, and this diode "trick" is specific to the particular input architecture used in those chips. So it doesn't apply to anything you're doing.

Now, many op-amps do benefit from input voltage limiting diodes if they're likely to get overdriven or sometimes operate "open loop", e.g. as comparators, rectifiers, one-quadrant power supply regulators, etc. You put two antiparallel diodes between the (+) and (-) inputs. This improves the overdrive recovery performance of most op-amps, including LM358, but is not very relevant in linear audio applications. The only benefit of those input diodes would be to make the amplifier recover quicker from pulses ("pops") on the input. That's about it, and these diodes will not conduct during normal operation. And when placed in front of very good op-amps, they actually **add** distortion! Not something you'd observe with an equivalent of a LM741, though: its own distortion overshadows anything an input diode would add.

You can improve a LM358/LM324's output stage distortion by loading it to operate the output stage in Class A, vs. the usual class "aB" (in audio use it's IIRC more like class B). It won't make it a great audio op-amp though - it's way too slow for audio. The slew rate is so bad that you'll need to run it on fairly small signals. The GBW forces small gains for audio use. I'd say LM358/324 can "do" rudimentary audio up to maybe gain 3, and a couple volts of output amplitude at most.

To linearize the output stage in op-amps of similar design, add a pull-down resistor of several kohm to negative supply rail. Choose the value to provide 0.5-1mA of load at idle. This should keep the NPN doing all the work in Class A. An actual current source set to 1mA would be even better.

This doesn't fix any distortions introduced by the internal structure of the op-amp, though. But it gets you all you can get from an LM358 - a part rather ill-suited for audio use.

Many modern $0.50 surface mount rail-to-rail op-amps will perform miles better than an LM358 for audio.

But if you insist on going "old skool", then don't settle for an LM358. Use a TL072 - a design of similar vintage, costs about the same and performs way better - although still it helps to keep the output stage loaded with a current source to keep it mostly class A.

Comment: I used many TL071 single, TL072 dual and TL074 quad audio opamps in most of my circuits. They are inexpensive because they are/were made by the billions for hifi systems.

Answer (score 0):

The NJM12904 is a copy of the old LM324, LM358 and LM2904 that were designed for LOW quiescent current. The current was reduced by removing the class-AB bias in the output transistors causing class-B crossover distortion. Other reductions in quiescent current cause audio hiss and a poor slew rate with poor performance above only 2.5kHz which is why thewy are never used for audio.
[image]

Comment: You should have mentioned that there was a previous NJM2904 op amp that they came out with and that the NJM12904 is an improved version of their 2904 design.

Comment: The diodes do not improve the awful performance. The diodes simply conduct when somebody tries to damage the inputs or output.

Answer (score 0):

You’d be better of with an [NJM4558](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/294/NJM4558_NJM4559_E-218630.pdf) which is a dual version of the much-beloved LM741 and is suitable for low grade audio.

Comment: I had problems with a similar device RC4558, which exhibited phase reversal when inputs were close to the negative supply rail. I had it in a single 5V supply circuit, where I had specified a TLC272 or TLE2142, but somehow the 4558s were in the same bin. The old school LM358 would have been OK. https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/rc4558.pdf

Comment: Given that the topic of op amps & their ideosyncracies comes up often, is there a good online resource that lists all of them?

Comment: I have no idea why people say any 4558 based op amp is a dual 741 op amp. The 4558 has way higher specs for slew rate or even GBW, etc and performs way better. Even though the 4558 has the same GBW as an TL07X series op amp, I would prefer the TL07X based op amp.

Comment: The 4558 dual "electric guitar" opamp is 4 years older than the TL071, TL072 and TL074 "hifi audio" opamps.

Comment: @MichaelWeaser the somewhat tongue-in-cheek reference to the 741 is because just about every xx4558 datasheet refers to them as being dual 741s. As you rightly point out, some aspects of the performance are significantly better. Perhaps an indication of the market dominance of the 741 when they were introduced.

Answer (score 0):

The LM324 can be used for audio too, you just need to add a pull down resistor to prevent cross-over distortion.

December 1994 National semiconductor LM124(etc.) datasheet bottom of page 6 column 1:

> For ac applications, where the load is capacitively coupled
> to the output of the amplifier, a resistor should be used, from
> the output of the amplifier to ground to increase the class A
> bias current and prevent crossover distortion.

credit: Natsemi Via Datasheet Archiove

Comment: The LM324 is too noisy (hiss) for audio and it has trouble with its poor slew rate with frequencies above 2kHz at high levels. The newest Japanese LM2904 copy's datasheet has no audio specs and also has the same problems.